# Does Android use SQLITE in "Shared-Cache Mode"?

Tags: android, sqlite

SQLite has a "Shared-Cache Mode"
http://www.sqlite.org/sharedcache.html

and it shows that it may cause database corruption bug
http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html

I want to know, can we use this mode in Android? If we can, where is the API?

In `nativeOpen()`, I cannot find the openflags `SQLITE_SHAREDCACHE`, and I am also looking for API relating the sqlite function `sqlite3_enable_shared_cache()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have seen in the source, the Android database API does not use SQLite's shared cache mode.

Comment: As I can see in the source code, `android.database` API holds a session/connection per thread. But Room's InvalidationTracker uses triggers and temporary tables and works fine despite it is not pinned to any particular thread. The same technique does not work outside of Android, e.g. with xerial/sqlite-jdbc driver. How's that, isn't it shared cache mode?

Comment: @Miha_x64 Shared-cache mode must be explicitly enabled, and Android does not do it. If you want to know how Room works (I don't either), ask a new question.